# how to get current file name in node js when use type ES

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

module p.js

```
import url from 'url';

export function _file(){
    return url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
}
```

index.js

```
import {_file} from './p.js';

console.log(_file()); // returns p.js instead of index.js
```

i want the index.js file address to be returned.

i know can pass the import.meta.url in the index.js as a method parameter, but I want to know if there is another way or not ???

Comment: Why do you need this? You already hardcoded the file name into `index.js`: `import ... from './p.js';`. Why do you need it "dynamically"?

Comment: i need for avoid duplicate code and shorthanding

Answer (score 1):

There is not.

The module knows its own filename.

It doesn't know the name of some file some arbitrary distance up the stack.